# Actual and formal length error in both classes

Tags: java

I'm doing this project for school.

Basically you enter any phrases and the program break it down into the number of specific letters into an array and the most occurring letter.

ex.

```
I am not Santa 

Santa lives in the north pole 

Santa is not Canadian

a=10

b=0

c=1
```

and so on, plus

```
most occuring=a
```

This is my Main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LetterDriver{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] lines = new String[3];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter any phrases, then press enter");
    int pos = 0;
    String tScan = " ";
    while(tScan.length() > 0){
      tScan = scan.nextLine();
      lines[pos] = tScan;
      pos++;
    }
    LetterProfile.printResults(tScan);//ERROR, I feel it's a syntax issue here, but I can't figure it out.
  }
}
```

and this is my other class:

```
public class LetterProfile{

  int cCount[] = new int [26];

  public void countChars (String s){
    s.toLowerCase();
    char a = 'a';
    for (int i =0;i < s.length();i++){
      int pos = (int)s.charAt(i) -(int) a;
      if ( pos >=0 && pos < 26){
        cCount[pos]++;
      }
    }
  }
  public int mostOccur(){
    int largest = 0;
    int largestindex = 0;
    for(int a = 0; a < 26; a++){
      if(cCount[a] > largest){
        largest = cCount[a];
      }
    }
    return (largestindex);
  }
  public void printResults(){
    System.out.println(this.mostOccur());
  }
  public void runProg(String a){
    a.countChars();
    System.out.println(mostOccur(a));  //ERROR
  }
}
```

I've being working on this for about 5 hours, and I can't find anything wrong with it. I think all the parts I would need for the program is in there already, but I just need to organize it better.

it's giving me these errors:

```
2 errors found:
File: C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\LetterDriver.java  [line: 14]
Error: method printResults in class LetterProfile cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

File: C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\LetterProfile.java  [line: 30]
Error: method mostOccur in class LetterProfile cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: answers are in the error messages. check the parameter types for the methods.

Comment: I didn't realize that, I've being look at it for too long. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the error it seems you are trying to provide arguments to `printResults` and `mostOccur` method and they do not accept any

Change the followwing

from `System.out.println(mostOccur(a));` to `System.out.println(mostOccur());`

and

`LetterProfile.printResults(tScan);` to `LetterProfile.printResults();`